# How to take out x and y from my list so I can use it to create a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

> So I made my list but after that I don't know how to take out of it my x and y so I can use it later to create a graph

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tabuletson = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    x = round(random.uniform(-1000,1000),2)
    y = (2*x+1)
    tabuletson.append([x,y])

print(tabuletson)

wielomian = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,3))
linia = np.linspace(-2000,2000,2000)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(linia,wielomian(linia))
plt.show()
```

Comment: whats the problem in this code?

Comment: So I print 10 random numbers here and I want to use them later to make a graph but in this situation my x and y numbers exist only in my "for" so I can't use them later. I need to take them out of the list but don't really know how :/

Comment: Removed the `random` tag because whether the data is random or not doesn't affect your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to add one line of code after and outside your for loop. This command will create two lists containing x and y values. You can use the same variable names `x` and `y`.

```
x, y = zip(*tabuletson)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `np.polyfit` and `plt.scatter` functions you are using require separate lists of X and Y coordinates.

Try:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tabuletson_x = []
tabuletson_y = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    x = round(random.uniform(-1000,1000),2)
    y = (2*x+1)
    tabuletson_x.append(x)
    tabuletson_y.append(y)

print(tabuletson_x)
print(tabuletson_y)

wielomian = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(tabuletson_x,tabuletson_y,3))
linia = np.linspace(-2000,2000,2000)

plt.scatter(tabuletson_x,tabuletson_y)
plt.plot(linia,wielomian(linia))
plt.show()
```

Note: referencing `x` and `y` after the `for` cycle will give you the last values from the randomly generated list:

```
list of x vals:  [-8.78, 554.81, -693.22, 955.8, 88.95, 235.55, -108.67, -804.08, 494.65, 754.58]
list of y vals:  [-16.56, 1110.62, -1385.44, 1912.6, 178.9, 472.1, -216.34, -1607.16, 990.3, 1510.16]
x:  754.58
y:  1510.16
```

For more info:

[PyPlot Scatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

[PolyFit documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a better way to do what you want according of how `plt.scatter` and `plt.plot` work. Hope it works as you want!

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []; y = []

for i in range(10):
    x.append(round(random.uniform(-1000,1000),2))
    y.append(2*x[i]+1)

wielomian = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,3))
linia = np.linspace(-2000,2000,2000)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(linia,wielomian(linia))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your x and y are stored in your list `tabuletson`. Like this: [[x0,y0], [x1,y1], ..., [x,y]]

So you can, for example, get the value of x1 and y1 with `x1 = tabuletson[1][0]` and `y1 = tabuletson[1][1]`

Is that your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tabuletson = np.array(tabuletson)
X, Y = tabuletson[:,0], tabuletson[:,1]
```

**X** will have all your xs from list
And, **Y** will have all your ys from list